# How to not loose the parameter when instancing new form

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, showdialog

I have my Code like this:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        schema s1 = new schema(readedImage);
        s1.ShowDialog();
        if(s1.imgToReturn != null)
        {
            readedImage = s1.imgToReturn;
            s1.imgToReturn = null;
        }
        s1.Dispose();
    }
```

Because I am creating a new instance, i dont get the "readedImage" in the new form when calling the .ShowDialog() later.
Is there a way to give the parameters in the .ShowDialog Action?

edit:
this is the constructor of the shema form:

```
    public schema(Image readedImage = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imgToReturn = readedImage;
    }
```

Greetings and thanks for help

Comment: I am unsure what you're talking about, what does creating a new instance have to do with it? What do you mean you "dont get 'readedimage' in the new form?

Comment: My form "schema" has the constructor like this:
Schema(Image img = null)

And when I call the form like I did in the code i posted then i get the default "null" for img. 

Thats what i meant with "dont get the readedImage"

Comment: Instead of some vague description of `Schema`, just add the code.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, i added it in the Post now

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure what you mean in the question.

But I think this might help you

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    schema s1 = new schema(readedImage);
    if(s1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if(s1.imgToReturn != null)
        {
            readedImage = s1.imgToReturn;
            s1.imgToReturn = null;
        }
        s1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And in the dialog you are showing make sure to set the property `DialogResult` once the user is done and everything has worked out.

Comment: thx for the answer but i found the solution. It wasn't there. There was another bit of code who did the fault.